# Removal of selected Item in other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing issue such as below.
I have used 6 dropdown list in my page with similar values.
 Now I want that if one option is selected from dropdown lits then it should be removed from other dropdown list, and vice versa.
 working code is as below :

```
var $selects = $('select');
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('option:hidden', $selects).each(function () {
            var self = this,
                toShow = true;
            $selects.not($(this).parent()).each(function () {
                if (self.value == this.value) toShow = false;
            })
            if (toShow) $(this).show();
        });
        if (this.value != 0) //to keep default option available
          $selects.not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').hide();
    });
```

But above code works fine in case we change dropdown item by mouse click however when we use aero keys the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Please Do like Below

```
var textValue = $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").val();
$("#dropdownElement").find('option[value="'+textValue+'" ]').remove();
```

This will helps you.

Comment: It will work. However I cant remove option as drop down option may be change by any user then removed item should be displayed in other drop down accordingly.

Comment: I checked the updated code it helps good please Try it. I have updated the code.

Comment: Please let me know does it helps or not

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/b5ahtbr5/1/

Here is what you do-

```
$('.dropdown').on('change',function(){
    var selectedValue=$('option:selected',this).val();
  $('.dropdown ').not(this).find('option[value='+selectedValue+']').remove();
});
```